# Common wrapper for methods

Tags: java

Is it possible to implement some common wrapper aka following "pseudo code":

```
Function calculateFunction = () -> sampleService.calculate("a", "b", 1L);
CalculationResult result = wrapCall(calculateFunction);

Function testFunction = () -> anotherService.test(parameters);
TestResult result = wrapCall(testFunction);

public R wrapCall(Function<T,R> function) {
    log.debug("...");
    try {
        R result = function.apply();
        log.debug("...");
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("...")
        throw new RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1** I added new statement throwing RuntimeException

**UPDATE 2** The isssue with the code was that it won't compile becuase of wrong Function type with T parameter and missing < R > in wrapCall method definition. Here is what I was looking for:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Operation<R> {
    R action();
}

public <R> R wrapCall(Operation<R> function) {
    try {
        R result = function.action();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

Operation<String> operation = () -> sampleService.calculate("a", "b", 1L);

String result = wrapCall(operation);
```

Comment: You already did that. No ?

Comment: Except a missing `return` in case of an exception, I don't see a problem in this pseudo code. Just need a correct usage of Generic type with the function and the return

Comment: You can always use `Reflection API` for that - mass method, and object that method is goind to be invoked on.

Comment: To add information to your pseudo code : `public R wrapCall(Function<R> function) {` where in `Function<R>`, `R` is the return type of the function. PS : In reality, it is `Function<T,R>` but this is still pseudo code ;) EDIT : Define what you want exactly. Your pseudo code is correct (not correctly exact for Java, but pseudo-code don't need to be)

Comment: Here is my latest code that will not compile: `    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface MyFunction<R> {
        R action();
    }


    public R wrapCall(MyFunction<R> function) {
        try {
            R result = function.action();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public interface Operation<T> {
    T execute();
}

public class Executor {
    //...
    public <T> T execute(final Operation<T> operation) {
        log.debug("something");
        try {
            final T result = operation.execute();
            log.debug(result);
            return result;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            log.error("error", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("omg", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the interface through anonymous implementations with lamdbdas:

```
final Integer i = new Executor().execute(
    () -> Integer.parseInt("5")
);
```

Comment: You forgot a `return` in case of an exception ;)

Comment: Ah, there we go..

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I was missing "<R>" in the definition of execute method.